geyser plugin error while loading config file
I have this error while trying to run this plugin on WSL2:
jpgn:~/solana/geyser-postgres$ solana-test-validator --geyser-plugin-config ./config/config.json
--faucet-sol argument ignored, ledger already exists
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
Aborted

Versions:
jpgn:~/solana/geyser-postgres$ solana --version
solana-cli 1.18.22 (src:8da66fa6; feat:4215500110, client:Agave)
jpgn:~/solana/geyser-postgres$ solana-test-validator -V
solana-test-validator 1.18.22 (src:8da66fa6; feat:4215500110, client:Agave)
jpgn:~/solana/geyser-postgres$ cargo --version
cargo 1.80.0 (376290515 2024-07-16)
jpgn:~/solana/geyser-postgres$ rustc --version
rustc 1.80.0 (051478957 2024-07-21)

All tests in /src/lib.rs have passed successfully.
I use this config.json file:
{
    "libpath": "/home/jpgn/solana/geyser-postgres/target/release/libsolana_geyser_plugin_postgres.so",
    "host": "localhost",
    "user": "solana",
    "port": 5432,
    "threads": 20,
    "batch_size": 20,
    "panic_on_db_errors": true,
    "accounts_selector" : {
        "accounts" : ["*"]
    },
    "transaction_selector" : {
        "mentions" : ["*"]
    }
}

And I get this error:
jpgn:~/solana/geyser-postgres$ cat test-ledger/validator.log
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.881621320Z INFO  solana_test_validator] agave-validator 1.18.22 (src:8da66fa6; feat:4215500110, client:Agave)
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.881654606Z INFO  solana_test_validator] Starting validator with: ArgsOs {
        inner: [
            "solana-test-validator",
            "--geyser-plugin-config",
            "./config/config.json",
        ],
    }
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.881666174Z WARN  solana_perf] CUDA is disabled
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.881673207Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX detected
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.881674583Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX2 detected
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.883289611Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet started. Listening on: 0.0.0.0:9900
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.883307428Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet account address: 88kwZJpdBThm8pSRRAroY81MVbxvm5dg7steYRjbSDZg
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.884418540Z INFO  agave_validator::admin_rpc_service] started admin rpc service!
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.885412729Z INFO  solana_test_validator] Feature for 41tVp5qR1XwWRt5WifvtSQyuxtqQWJgEK8w91AtBqSwP deactivated
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.885726982Z INFO  solana_core::validator] identity pubkey: EYH9bs3aNs3J7H5AcpzPpNWnazDhLdneBrupn2BxyuN1
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.885739691Z INFO  solana_core::validator] vote account pubkey: CPBp9Ba34yjDLjtoneHBVvcUJ8vTRnQz32HfPiEnbQKa
[2024-08-25T22:38:17.885758863Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_manager::geyser_plugin_service] Starting GeyserPluginService from config files: ["./config/config.json"]
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:2431:38:
byte index 1 is not a char boundary; it is inside '\u{1a}' (bytes 2..3) of `s5s5rxs5rxs5s5rxs5s5s5s5s5s5s50s5s5s5 s5Ps5s5ps5s5s5ps5`[...]
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
   2: core::str::slice_error_fail_rt
   3: core::str::slice_error_fail
   4: <str as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
   5: core::fmt::write
   6: core::fmt::write
   7: env_logger::fmt::Builder::build::{{closure}}
   8: <env_logger::Logger as log::Log>::log::{{closure}}
   9: <env_logger::Logger as log::Log>::log
  10: <solana_logger::LoggerShim as log::Log>::log
  11: log::__private_api::log_impl
  12: <solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::geyser_plugin_postgres::GeyserPluginPostgres as solana_geyser_plugin_interface::geyser_plugin_interface::GeyserPlugin>::on_load
  13: solana_geyser_plugin_manager::geyser_plugin_manager::LoadedGeyserPlugin::new
  14: solana_geyser_plugin_manager::geyser_plugin_manager::load_plugin_from_config
  15: solana_geyser_plugin_manager::geyser_plugin_manager::GeyserPluginManager::load_plugin
  16: solana_geyser_plugin_manager::geyser_plugin_service::GeyserPluginService::new_with_receiver
  17: solana_core::validator::Validator::new
  18: solana_test_validator::TestValidator::start
  19: solana_test_validator::TestValidatorGenesis::start_with_mint_address_and_geyser_plugin_rpc
  20: solana_test_validator::main
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
fatal runtime error: Rust cannot catch foreign exceptions

Changing 'cargo.toml' references to '1.18.22' abort in this way:
jpgn@W10:~/solana/geyser-postgres$ solana-test-validator --geyser-plugin-config ./config/config.json
--faucet-sol argument ignored, ledger already exists
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠤ Initializing...                                                                                                       Segmentation fault

Error log:
jpgn@W10:~/solana/geyser-postgres$ cat test-ledger/validator.log
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.232748262Z INFO  solana_test_validator] agave-validator 1.18.22 (src:8da66fa6; feat:4215500110, client:Agave)
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.232797850Z INFO  solana_test_validator] Starting validator with: ArgsOs {
        inner: [
            "solana-test-validator",
            "--geyser-plugin-config",
            "./config/config.json",
        ],
    }
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.232815272Z WARN  solana_perf] CUDA is disabled
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.232825454Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX detected
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.232828084Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX2 detected
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.235036575Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet started. Listening on: 0.0.0.0:9900
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.235076660Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet account address: 8a83ZXxAvjGcL6GavAWbtE4o31KkfCtyGujrtNgTEwha
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.235727770Z INFO  agave_validator::admin_rpc_service] started admin rpc service!
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.239003474Z INFO  solana_test_validator] Feature for 41tVp5qR1XwWRt5WifvtSQyuxtqQWJgEK8w91AtBqSwP deactivated
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.239550415Z INFO  solana_core::validator] identity pubkey: GNPHra6zvSjyofmmjrPb4NmrdvQnjzFwb96KUsz5vqXC
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.239588343Z INFO  solana_core::validator] vote account pubkey: 488c35qm8VFF2TPBhjUroo7vReV53LSH4MCxzBR1rcDG
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.239624514Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_manager::geyser_plugin_service] Starting GeyserPluginService from config files: ["./config/config.json"]
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.245278148Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::geyser_plugin_postgres] Loading plugin "GeyserPluginPostgres" from config_file "./config/config.json"
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.245347595Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::accounts_selector] Creating AccountsSelector from accounts: ["*"], owners: []
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.245352944Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::transaction_selector] Creating TransactionSelector from addresses: ["*"]
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.245361196Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Creating ParallelPostgresClient...
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.246725611Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Creating SimplePostgresClient...
...
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.252599279Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] INSERT INTO account AS acct (pubkey, slot, owner, lamports, executable, rent_epoch, data, write_version, updated_on, txn_signature) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10), ($11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20), ($21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30), ($31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40), ($41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50), ($51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $60), ($61, $62, $63, $64, $65, $66, $67, $68, $69, $70), ($71, $72, $73, $74, $75, $76, $77, $78, $79, $80), ($81, $82, $83, $84, $85, $86, $87, $88, $89, $90), ($91, $92, $93, $94, $95, $96, $97, $98, $99, $100), ($101, $102, $103, $104, $105, $106, $107, $108, $109, $110), ($111, $112, $113, $114, $115, $116, $117, $118, $119, $120), ($121, $122, $123, $124, $125, $126, $127, $128, $129, $130), ($131, $132, $133, $134, $135, $136, $137, $138, $139, $140), ($141, $142, $143, $144, $145, $146, $147, $148, $149, $150), ($151, $152, $153, $154, $155, $156, $157, $158, $159, $160), ($161, $162, $163, $164, $165, $166, $167, $168, $169, $170), ($171, $172, $173, $174, $175, $176, $177, $178, $179, $180), ($181, $182, $183, $184, $185, $186, $187, $188, $189, $190), ($191, $192, $193, $194, $195, $196, $197, $198, $199, $200) ON CONFLICT (pubkey) DO UPDATE SET slot=excluded.slot, owner=excluded.owner, lamports=excluded.lamports, executable=excluded.executable, rent_epoch=excluded.rent_epoch, data=excluded.data, write_version=excluded.write_version, updated_on=excluded.updated_on, txn_signature=excluded.txn_signature WHERE acct.slot < excluded.slot OR (acct.slot = excluded.slot AND acct.write_version < excluded.write_version)
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.253999827Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Creating SimplePostgresClient...
...
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.258769879Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_manager::geyser_plugin_service] Started GeyserPluginService
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.258802704Z WARN  solana_core::validator] authorized voter: 488c35qm8VFF2TPBhjUroo7vReV53LSH4MCxzBR1rcDG
...
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.267247314Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Created SimplePostgresClient.
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.268061688Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] INSERT INTO account AS acct (pubkey, slot, owner, lamports, executable, rent_epoch, data, write_version, updated_on, txn_signature) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10), ($11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20), ($21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30), ($31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40), ($41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50), ($51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $60), ($61, $62, $63, $64, $65, $66, $67, $68, $69, $70), ($71, $72, $73, $74, $75, $76, $77, $78, $79, $80), ($81, $82, $83, $84, $85, $86, $87, $88, $89, $90), ($91, $92, $93, $94, $95, $96, $97, $98, $99, $100), ($101, $102, $103, $104, $105, $106, $107, $108, $109, $110), ($111, $112, $113, $114, $115, $116, $117, $118, $119, $120), ($121, $122, $123, $124, $125, $126, $127, $128, $129, $130), ($131, $132, $133, $134, $135, $136, $137, $138, $139, $140), ($141, $142, $143, $144, $145, $146, $147, $148, $149, $150), ($151, $152, $153, $154, $155, $156, $157, $158, $159, $160), ($161, $162, $163, $164, $165, $166, $167, $168, $169, $170), ($171, $172, $173, $174, $175, $176, $177, $178, $179, $180), ($181, $182, $183, $184, $185, $186, $187, $188, $189, $190), ($191, $192, $193, $194, $195, $196, $197, $198, $199, $200) ON CONFLICT (pubkey) DO UPDATE SET slot=excluded.slot, owner=excluded.owner, lamports=excluded.lamports, executable=excluded.executable, rent_epoch=excluded.rent_epoch, data=excluded.data, write_version=excluded.write_version, updated_on=excluded.updated_on, txn_signature=excluded.txn_signature WHERE acct.slot < excluded.slot OR (acct.slot = excluded.slot AND acct.write_version < excluded.write_version)
...
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.271164964Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Created SimplePostgresClient.
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.271206219Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Initializing sigverify...
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.271240259Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Initializing sigverify done.
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.271453439Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] INSERT INTO account AS acct (pubkey, slot, owner, lamports, executable, rent_epoch, data, write_version, updated_on, txn_signature) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10), ($11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20), ($21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30), ($31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40), ($41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50), ($51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $60), ($61, $62, $63, $64, $65, $66, $67, $68, $69, $70), ($71, $72, $73, $74, $75, $76, $77, $78, $79, $80), ($81, $82, $83, $84, $85, $86, $87, $88, $89, $90), ($91, $92, $93, $94, $95, $96, $97, $98, $99, $100), ($101, $102, $103, $104, $105, $106, $107, $108, $109, $110), ($111, $112, $113, $114, $115, $116, $117, $118, $119, $120), ($121, $122, $123, $124, $125, $126, $127, $128, $129, $130), ($131, $132, $133, $134, $135, $136, $137, $138, $139, $140), ($141, $142, $143, $144, $145, $146, $147, $148, $149, $150), ($151, $152, $153, $154, $155, $156, $157, $158, $159, $160), ($161, $162, $163, $164, $165, $166, $167, $168, $169, $170), ($171, $172, $173, $174, $175, $176, $177, $178, $179, $180), ($181, $182, $183, $184, $185, $186, $187, $188, $189, $190), ($191, $192, $193, $194, $195, $196, $197, $198, $199, $200) ON CONFLICT (pubkey) DO UPDATE SET slot=excluded.slot, owner=excluded.owner, lamports=excluded.lamports, executable=excluded.executable, rent_epoch=excluded.rent_epoch, data=excluded.data, write_version=excluded.write_version, updated_on=excluded.updated_on, txn_signature=excluded.txn_signature WHERE acct.slot < excluded.slot OR (acct.slot = excluded.slot AND acct.write_version < excluded.write_version)
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.271730368Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Created SimplePostgresClient.
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.272321989Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Cleaning accounts paths..
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.271993669Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Created SimplePostgresClient.
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.272862087Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Cleaning accounts paths done. clean_accounts_paths took 508us
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.272904451Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Created SimplePostgresClient.
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.273025931Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Cleaning orphaned account snapshot directories..
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.273072305Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Cleaning orphaned account snapshot directories done. clean_orphaned_account_snapshot_dirs took 38us
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.273087143Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Geyser plugin: accounts_update_notifier: true, transaction_notifier: true, entry_notifier: false
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.273098091Z INFO  solana_core::system_monitor_service] Starting SystemMonitorService
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.273297419Z INFO  solana_core::validator] loading ledger from "test-ledger"...
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.274089605Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Created SimplePostgresClient.
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.275571035Z INFO  solana_core::validator] genesis hash: A19KJoJCw63nEeJrGL1bawbGY174CJVgGYpUUPSdX6M4
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.275635736Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Maximum open file descriptors: 1000000
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.275639759Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Created SimplePostgresClient.
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.275647317Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Opening blockstore at "test-ledger/rocksdb"
[2024-09-10T18:39:52.275750778Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Created SimplePostgresClient.
...
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.313679125Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Opening blockstore done; blockstore open took 1.0s
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.314886509Z INFO  solana_ledger::bank_forks_utils] Initializing bank snapshots dir: test-ledger/snapshot
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.314926216Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_bank_utils] Loading bank from snapshot dir: test-ledger/snapshot/1301
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.315778395Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_bank_utils] rebuild storages from snapshot dir took 843us
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.315796309Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_bank_utils] Rebuilding bank from snapshot test-ledger/snapshot/1301
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.319976894Z INFO  solana_accounts_db::accounts_db] Background account hasher has started
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.326494662Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::geyser_plugin_postgres] Notifying the end of startup for accounts notifications
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.326529751Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Notifying the end of startup
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.326532887Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Startup done count: 0, good worker thread count: 20
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.327780017Z INFO  solana_accounts_db::accounts_db] rent_collector: RentCollector { epoch: 0, epoch_schedule: EpochSchedule { slots_per_epoch: 432000, leader_schedule_slot_offset: 432000, warmup: false, first_normal_epoch: 0, first_normal_slot: 0 }, slots_per_year: 78892314.984, rent: Rent { lamports_per_byte_year: 3480, exemption_threshold: 2.0, burn_percent: 50 } }
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.426777883Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Startup done count: 0, good worker thread count: 20
...
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.829885572Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] metrics disabled: environment variable not found
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.830320498Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: geyser_plugin_notify_account_restore_from_snapshot_summary flush_slots-us=389i flush-slots-counts=1i
...
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.832730881Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Startup done count: 9, good worker thread count: 20
...
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.865496813Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: geyser_plugin_notify_account_restore_from_snapshot_summary flush_slots-us=346i flush-slots-counts=2i
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.932882789Z INFO  solana_geyser_plugin_postgres::postgres_client] Done with notifying the end of startup
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.932956610Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] metrics disabled: environment variable not found
[2024-09-10T18:39:53.933782529Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accountsdb_plugin_notify_account_restore_from_snapshot_summary total_accounts=229i skipped_accounts=6i notified_accounts=0i elapsed_filtering_us=38i elapsed_notifying_us=6610i total_pure_notify_us=5992i total_pure_bookeeping_us=430i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.133410271Z INFO  solana_accounts_db::accounts_db] accounts data len: 1045662
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.133489157Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: generate_index overall_us=813634i total_us=537i scan_stores_us=6i insertion_time_us=39i min_bin_size=0i max_bin_size=0i storage_size_storages_us=5i index_flush_us=794692i total_rent_paying=0i amount_to_top_off_rent=0i total_items_including_duplicates=229i total_items=0i accounts_data_len_dedup_time_us=2178i total_duplicate_slot_keys=12i populate_duplicate_keys_us=8567i total_slots=3i slots_to_clean=2i copy_data_us=0i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.133516159Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: reconstruct_accountsdb_from_fields() accountsdb-notify-at-start-us=813682i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.134366799Z INFO  solana_runtime::serde_snapshot] rent_collector: RentCollector { epoch: 0, epoch_schedule: EpochSchedule { slots_per_epoch: 432000, leader_schedule_slot_offset: 432000, warmup: false, first_normal_epoch: 0, first_normal_slot: 0 }, slots_per_year: 78892314.984, rent: Rent { lamports_per_byte_year: 3480, exemption_threshold: 2.0, burn_percent: 50 } }
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.134378714Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: bank-new-from-fields accounts_data_len-from-snapshot=1045662i accounts_data_len-from-generate_index=1045662i stakes_accounts_load_duration_us=24i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.134410805Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_bank_utils] Rebuilding status cache from test-ledger/snapshot/1301/status_cache
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.134886708Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_bank_utils] Rebuilt bank for slot: 1301
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.134916993Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_bank_utils] rebuild bank from snapshot took 819ms
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.134987003Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: bank_from_snapshot_dir rebuild_storages_us=843i rebuild_bank_us=819120i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.158511564Z INFO  solana_core::validator] ContactInfo { pubkey: GNPHra6zvSjyofmmjrPb4NmrdvQnjzFwb96KUsz5vqXC, wallclock: 1725993594158, outset: 1725993592239513, shred_version: 25984, version: 1.18.22 (src:8da66fa6; feat:4215500110, client:Agave), addrs: [127.0.0.1], sockets: [SocketEntry { key: 0, index: 0, offset: 1024 }, SocketEntry { key: 10, index: 0, offset: 1 }, SocketEntry { key: 11, index: 0, offset: 1 }, SocketEntry { key: 5, index: 0, offset: 1 }, SocketEntry { key: 6, index: 0, offset: 1 }, SocketEntry { key: 9, index: 0, offset: 1 }, SocketEntry { key: 4, index: 0, offset: 3 }, SocketEntry { key: 8, index: 0, offset: 1 }, SocketEntry { key: 7, index: 0, offset: 1 }, SocketEntry { key: 1, index: 0, offset: 1 }, SocketEntry { key: 2, index: 0, offset: 7864 }, SocketEntry { key: 3, index: 0, offset: 1 }], extensions: [], cache: [127.0.0.1:1024, 127.0.0.1:1035, 127.0.0.1:8899, 127.0.0.1:8900, 127.0.0.1:1032, 127.0.0.1:1027, 127.0.0.1:1028, 127.0.0.1:1034, 127.0.0.1:1033, 127.0.0.1:1029, 127.0.0.1:1025, 127.0.0.1:1026] }
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.158563657Z INFO  solana_core::validator] local gossip address: 0.0.0.0:1024
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.158568218Z INFO  solana_core::validator] local broadcast address: 0.0.0.0:1036
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.158569982Z INFO  solana_core::validator] local repair address: 0.0.0.0:1031
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.158571427Z INFO  solana_core::validator] local retransmit address: 0.0.0.0:1030
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.159053423Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Using: block-verification-method: blockstore-processor, block-production-method: thread-local-multi-iterator
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.159086860Z INFO  solana_core::validator] no scheduler pool is installed for block verification...
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.159091566Z INFO  solana_core::sample_performance_service] Starting SamplePerformance service
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.159874500Z INFO  solana_runtime::accounts_background_service] AccountsBackgroundService has started
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.160230539Z INFO  solana_accounts_db::accounts_db] total_stores: 3, newest_slot: 1301, oldest_slot: 0
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.160259054Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_db_active flush=1i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.160280349Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_db-flush_accounts_cache total_new_cleaned_roots=0i num_cleaned_roots_flushed=0i total_new_excess_roots=0i num_excess_roots_flushed=0i excess_slot_count=0i unflushable_unrooted_slot_count=0i flush_roots_elapsed=34i account_bytes_saved=0i num_accounts_saved=0i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.160285321Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_db_active flush=0i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.160287674Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_db_active clean=1i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.160305388Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_db-stores total_count=3i recycle_count=0i total_bytes=1239616i total_alive_bytes=1245184i total_alive_ratio=1.00449171356291
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.160308473Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_db-perf-stats delta_hash_num=0i delta_hash_scan_us=0i delta_hash_accumulate_us=0i skipped_rewrites_num=0i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.161282733Z INFO  solana_core::snapshot_packager_service] SnapshotPackagerService has started
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.162001107Z INFO  solana_core::accounts_hash_verifier] AccountsHashVerifier has started
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.162774701Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: clean_purge_slots_stats safety_checks_elapsed=0i remove_cache_elapsed=0i remove_storage_entries_elapsed=0i drop_storage_entries_elapsed=0i num_cached_slots_removed=0i num_stored_slots_removed=0i total_removed_storage_entries=0i total_removed_cached_bytes=0i total_removed_stored_bytes=0i recycle_stores_write_elapsed=0i scan_storages_elapsed=0i purge_accounts_index_elapsed=0i handle_reclaims_elapsed=0i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.162816977Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_index_roots_len roots_len=0i uncleaned_roots_len=0i roots_range_width=0i unrooted_cleaned_count=0i rooted_cleaned_count=0i clean_unref_from_storage_us=0i clean_dead_slot_us=0i append_vecs_open=3i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.162824797Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: clean_accounts total_us=2508i collect_delta_keys_us=7i oldest_dirty_slot=1301i pubkeys_removed_from_accounts_index=0i dirty_ancient_stores=0i dirty_store_processing_us=1910i accounts_scan=170i clean_old_rooted=11i store_counts=0i purge_filter=0i calc_deps=0i reclaims=2i delta_insert_us=174i delta_key_count=6i dirty_pubkeys_count=0i sort_us=177i useful_keys=6i total_keys_count=6i scan_found_not_zero=6i scan_not_found_on_fork=0i scan_missing=0i uncleaned_roots_len=2i clean_old_root_us=7i clean_old_root_reclaim_us=0i reset_uncleaned_roots_us=2i remove_dead_accounts_remove_us=0i remove_dead_accounts_shrink_us=0i clean_stored_dead_slots_us=0i roots_added=3i roots_removed=0i active_scans=0i max_distance_to_min_scan_slot=0i ancient_account_cleans=0i next_store_id=15i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.162832588Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_db_active clean=0i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.473659310Z INFO  solana_connection_cache::connection_cache] Creating ConnectionCache connection_cache_tpu_quic, pool size: 1
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.474441357Z INFO  solana_rpc::rpc_service] rpc bound to 0.0.0.0:8899
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.474461606Z INFO  solana_rpc::rpc_service] rpc configuration: JsonRpcConfig { enable_rpc_transaction_history: true, enable_extended_tx_metadata_storage: true, faucet_addr: Some(0.0.0.0:9900), health_check_slot_distance: 0, rpc_bigtable_config: None, max_multiple_accounts: None, account_indexes: AccountSecondaryIndexes { keys: None, indexes: {} }, rpc_threads: 0, rpc_niceness_adj: 0, full_api: true, obsolete_v1_7_api: false, rpc_scan_and_fix_roots: false, max_request_body_size: None, disable_health_check: true }
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.474557694Z INFO  solana_send_transaction_service::send_transaction_service] Starting send-transaction-service::receive_txn_thread with config Config { retry_rate_ms: 2000, leader_forward_count: 2, default_max_retries: None, service_max_retries: 18446744073709551615, batch_size: 1, batch_send_rate_ms: 1, tpu_peers: None }
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.474608416Z INFO  solana_send_transaction_service::send_transaction_service] Starting send-transaction-service::retry_thread with config Config { retry_rate_ms: 2000, leader_forward_count: 2, default_max_retries: None, service_max_retries: 18446744073709551615, batch_size: 1, batch_send_rate_ms: 1, tpu_peers: None }
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.475217717Z INFO  solana_rpc::rpc_pubsub_service] rpc_pubsub bound to 0.0.0.0:8900
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.476236735Z INFO  solana_net_utils::ip_echo_server] bound to 0.0.0.0:1024
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.478881614Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Disabled banking trace
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.496754290Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore_processor] Processing ledger from slot 1301...
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.496863191Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore_processor] ledger holds data through slot 1387
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.496867921Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore_processor] load_frozen_forks() latest root from blockstore: 1355, max_root: 1355
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.496995939Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: bank-timestamp get_timestamp_estimate_us=1i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.497014445Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: bank-timestamp-correction slot=1302i from_genesis=1725993431i corrected=1725993535i ancestor_timestamp=1725993534i
[2024-09-10T18:39:54.497022096Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: bank-new_from_parent-heights slot=1302i block_height=1301i parent_slot=1301i bank_rc_creation_us=1i total_elapsed_us=143i status_cache_us=0i fee_components_us=0i blockhash_queue_us=3i stakes_cache_us=1i epoch_stakes_time_us=0i builtin_programs_us=0i rewards_pool_pubkeys_us=0i executor_cache_us=0i transaction_debug_keys_us=0i transaction_log_collector_config_us=0i feature_set_us=0i ancestors_us=2i update_epoch_us=1i recompilation_time_us=0i update_sysvars_us=98i fill_sysvar_cache_us=26i


Without looking too far into it, this might be due to some incompatibilities -- Solana 1.18 using Rust version 1.75, and the example you link hasn't been updated to the 1.18 crates, so you might have some issues bringing the two together. Typically, Geyser plugins need to be recompiled for each new version of the Solana validator

Thank you. Changing all references to Solana in Cargo.toml from 1.7.3 to 1.18.22 an changing on_load to add a boolen as third parameter... it compiles but drives to "Segmentation fault" after "Initilizing..." test message. No detailed error message,

@J.PabloGarcía Were you able to find a solution? I'm struggling with the same Segmentation fault.

@nibty Yes, I think the problem were versions and wrong folders rights, but I don't remember exactly. If you are working on the same example I can provide you my code (just let me know it).
